# What determines which configurable option shows first, second, etc?

Tags: configurable-product

I have configurable shirts with colors and sizes. Sizes show first in the detail view, but I want Colors to show first... how do I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the configurable product and then click on Associated Products on the left section, you can re-sort the configurable options.

About mid-way down the page under the header of 'Super product attributes configuration', you will see a section that looks like this:

[image: Super product attributes configuration]

You can hover over the little orange up/down arrows and drag/drop them into the order you prefer.

As a note, I belive the default sorting comes from which attribute was created first and thus gets the lower ID number (so it's sorting by ID number until you manually change it).